# Jquery Ui: Selectable - possible to select two list items with one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am using Jquery Ui: selectable on a list and am trying to figure out how to select two list elements with one click. I want it so that when a list item is clicked/selected, the next item in the list also gets selected.

**ASPX page:**

```html
<button id="joinButton" type="button" class="collapsible inactiveSequenceTitle">
    <span style="margin-left: 0.35em;" class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    &nbsp
    </span>Join Sections
</button>
<div id="joinBox" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <ul id="sortableJoin-1" style="width: 98%; margin: auto;"></ul>

    <div id="saveJoin">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="join">
            <span class="fa fa-save">
            &nbsp
            </span>Join 
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery/Jvascript:**

```js
$("#sortableJoin-1").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        var selected = $("li[class$='ui-selected']").length;
    }
    stop: function (e) {
        var last = $("li[class$='ui-selected']:last").index();
        $("li:eq(" + (last + 1) + ")").addClass("ui-selected");
    },
});

$('#sortableJoin-1').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the next item of the selected item using the [`stop`](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-stop) event which is triggered at the end of the select operation. Inside `stop`, get the index of the last element with the class `ui-selected` and add this class to the next element in the list.

```js
$("#sortableJoin-1").selectable({
  selected: function(event, ui) {
    var selected = $("li[class$='ui-selected']").length;
  },
  stop: function(e) {
   var last = $("li[class$='ui-selected']:last").index();
   $("li:eq(" + (last + 1) + ")").addClass("ui-selected");
  }
});
```

```css
 .ui-selected {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<button id="joinSectionsButton" type="button" class="collapsible inactiveSequenceTitle"><span style="margin-left: 0.35em;" class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus">&nbsp;</span>Join Sections</button>
<div id="joinSectionsBox" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <ul id="sortableJoin-1" style="width: 98%; margin: auto;">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="saveJoinSections">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="joinSections"><span class="fa fa-save">&nbsp;</span>Join Sections</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Unfortunately it didn't work. I've updated the code above accordingly. The "run code snippet" button wouldn't run either for some reason

Comment: @NickyLarson Strange that it's not working for you as it's working in the snippet above as well as in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qgeazj4d/1/

Comment: My work firewall was blocking the code snippet from running. I see it does work. Must be something up with my code, I'll figure it out, thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe it's not working for me because the <li> elements in my code are added dynamically and aren't explicit? still haven't managed to get this working

Comment: problem solved by changing it to this:             $("#sortableJoin-1 li:eq(" + (last + 1) + ")").addClass("ui-selected");